# MySQL command to Extract DDL and DML and Exclude tables which are not required?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db and looking for a mysql commands to extract Extract DDL and DML and Exclude tables which are not required

could you please let me know how we can do it via command prompt?

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqldump:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

able to dump DDL/DML and has option for exclude list of tables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table

Comment: can you pls specific the command for DDL as well as DML?

Comment: for ddl:

mysqldump -uroot -pmysql --no-data testdb > testdb_exported_ddl_file.sql

for dml:

mysqldump -uroot -pmysql --skip-triggers --no-create-info --ignore-table=testdb.emp_table --ignore-table=testdb.emp_history testdb > testdb_dml.sql